# Intersect query against delimited data. Taking too long to retrieve data. Need expert advice

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Facing challenge writing SQL select statement to retrieve delimited data. Can someone help advise me how to optimise  this query?

```
SELECT 
        [ID] as 'itemID', [ID] as 'noteLink', [ID] as 'editLink', [Firstname] as 'Firstname',[Lastname] as 'Lastname',[Company] as 'Company',
        [Address line 1] as 'Address1', [Address line 2] as 'Address2',[Address line 3] as Address3,[EmailAddress] as 'EmailAddress',
        [City] as 'City',[Phone] as 'Telephone', [Skills], [Career Level] as Careerlevel, [Newsletter Preferences] as NewsletterPreferences, 
        [Industries] 
    FROM [reportUserTable] 
        WHERE (ISNULL([company], '') = '') 
        AND SUBSTRING(added,1,8) > '20130716' 
        AND SUBSTRING(added,1,8) < '20131213' 
INTERSECT 
SELECT 
        [ID] as 'itemID', [ID] as 'noteLink', [ID] as 'editLink', [Firstname] as 'Firstname',[Lastname] as 'Lastname',[Company] as 'Company',
        [Address line 1] as 'Address1', [Address line 2] as 'Address2',[Address line 3] as Address3,[EmailAddress] as 'EmailAddress',[City] as 'City',
        [Phone] as 'Telephone', [Skills], [Career Level] as Careerlevel, [Newsletter Preferences] as NewsletterPreferences, [Industries] 
    FROM [reportUserTable] 
        WHERE (ISNULL([company], '') = '') 
        AND [Industries] LIKE '%{04F1BDA1-B693-4505-A816-6123B2CAEB04}%' 
        OR [Industries] LIKE '%{0A8A4015-1591-4D86-B8E7-E913FB500CA4}%'
```

[image]

Comment: Er, what's the datatype of `added`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'd be better off normalising your industries list into a many-many table, but this should be a bit quicker as it does not project twice then intersect:

```
SELECT 
    [ID] as 'itemID', [ID] as 'noteLink', [ID] as 'editLink', [Firstname] as 'Firstname',[Lastname] as 'Lastname',[Company] as 'Company',
    [Address line 1] as 'Address1', [Address line 2] as 'Address2',[Address line 3] as Address3,[EmailAddress] as 'EmailAddress',
    [City] as 'City',[Phone] as 'Telephone', [Skills], [Career Level] as Careerlevel, [Newsletter Preferences] as NewsletterPreferences, 
    [Industries] 
FROM [reportUserTable] 
    WHERE (ISNULL([company], '') = '') 
    AND SUBSTRING(added,1,8) > '20130716' 
    AND SUBSTRING(added,1,8) < '20131213' 
    AND [Industries] LIKE '%{04F1BDA1-B693-4505-A816-6123B2CAEB04}%' 
    OR [Industries] LIKE '%{0A8A4015-1591-4D86-B8E7-E913FB500CA4}%'
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what a closing bracket is doing at the end of your query?

Comment: It's a typing error. Would say typo but so requires comments to be at least 15 characters long.

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought you meant to silently address the never mentioned unbracketed OR issue (and so there was probably an *opening* bracket missing). I was wrong then. :)

Comment: Haha :) Anything is possible when you're coding with flu (and no, it's not a new programming language) But yes, there should be brackets around the and industries or industries clause.